# Configuring Stackdriver agent on Windows server to collect Qlik logs

Tags: google-compute-engine, windows-server-2012-r2, agent, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have installed Qliksense on GCE (Windows Server 2012 R2). I'm trying to configure the stackdriver agent to collect Qlik logs.

following is the format I'm using. Can any one let me know if this is the right way. All examples I see are for Linux servers.

```
<source>
    @type tail
    # Format 'none' indicates the log is unstructured (text).
    format none
    # The path of the log file.
    path C:\ProgramData\Qlik\Sense\Log\Engine\Audit\Engine.txt
    # The path of the position file that records where in the log file
    # we have processed already. This is useful when the agent
    # restarts.
    pos_file C:\ProgramData\Qliktest-unstructured-log.pos
    read_from_head true
    # The log tag for this log input.
    tag qliksense-log
</source>
```

Comment: We are using windows server 2012r2, able to fix the issue by replacing "\" with "/"

Comment: What do you mean by "the right way"? Have you completed configuration and tested whether the necessary features appear to be functioning correctly?